# Fine Uploader pass filename to signature endpoint

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm wanting to pass the filename to the signature endpoint so I can set the 
ContentDisposition to the actual file name on azure.

```
        var manualuploader = $("#fine-uploader").fineUploaderAzure({
            template: 'qq-template',
            signature: {
                endpoint: $("#fine-uploader").data("url"),                    
            },
        ...
```

That's what I currently have. I know for the callbacks you can use a function and within the function use getName (id). How would I get the name within the signature part of fineuploader so I can append it to the url and pass it as a param to my endpoint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you were able to send extra params with the signature GET request, you won't be able to set any headers/params on the actual file in azure since it isn't in azure at this point.

Instead, you should specify an [uploadSuccess.endpoint](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-azure.html#uploadSuccess.endpoint) option. Fine Uploader Azure will send a POST request to this endpoint with a number of parameters, including the filename, after the file is successfully in Azure. This is the appropriate time to make changes to the file.